# Can this approximate closed form of Apery's constant $\zeta(3)$ be improved?

Tags: riemann-zeta

I know that an approximate closed form is not really a solution. However, I would like to present a method that gives a closed form of $\zeta(3)$ that is accurate to the 5th decimal, hoping that it may help to find the exact expression

Consider a real function:
$g(x)=-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{8!}+\frac{x^{9}}{11!}-...$

This function $g(x)$ has infinite positive roots. Let's denote these roots by $r_i$. Because $g(x)$ is a function of $x^3$ every root $r_i$ should be a triple root. We can show that:

$g(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}{(1-\frac{x^3}{r_i^3})}$

On the other hand, roots of $g(x)=0$ are given by:
$2\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x)=e^{-\frac{3x}{2}}$. As $x$ increases, the exponential part assimptotes to zero and roots of the function become closer to the roots of a sine wave $2\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x)=0$. The roots of sine equation are easy to show:$\mu_i=\frac{(6i+1)\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}, i=1,2,3,...  $

Now, assuming that these two sets of roots ($r_i$ and $\mu_i$)  are close to eachother, we can write:
$g(x)\cong-\frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{x^3}{\mu_i^3})$
 or 
$g(x)\cong-\frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{(3\sqrt{3})^3x^3}{(6i+1)^3\pi^3})$

The coefficient for the $x^3$ must be equal to that of the infinite series of $g(x)$. 
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(3\sqrt{3})^3x^3}{(6i+1)^3\pi^3}\cong\frac{2x^3}{5!}$

and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(6i+1)^3}\cong\frac{2\pi^3}{5!(3\sqrt{3})^3}$ and we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(6i+1)^3}=\frac{(91\zeta(3)+2\sqrt{3}\pi^3)}{216}-1$ combining these two equations gives us an approximate closed form of $\zeta(3)$:

$\zeta(3)\cong\frac{4(7290-67\sqrt{3}\pi^3)}{12285}$

which is accurate to the fifth decimal. This method is analogous to Euler's derivation of $\zeta(2)$ except that the roots of this function $g(x)$ are slightly nonlinear. Is it possible to reduce the error in the approximation of the roots $r_i$ by $\mu_i$?

Comment: A really interesting Eulerian-like method.

Comment: I allow myself to think the young Majid would love to prove the Riemann Hypothesis. Who knows? Best wishes for him.

Comment: @Ataulfo Thanks very much for your kind words.

Comment: There is one minor issue with your work that I noticed. $1-\frac{x^3}{r^3}$ has three distinct complex roots, since every number except zero has three distinct complex third roots. Thus, $r\omega$ and $r\omega^2$ are also roots with $\omega$ as the first complex third root of unity. I am not sure that hurts anything, though, with the result.

Comment: @TerraHyde: The roots come in form of complex triplets but if you multiply every three of them together they always form ${1-\frac{x^3}{r_i^3}}$ where ${r_i}$ is real.

Comment: @MajidFekri, the point of my previous comment is that, at one point, you said "Because $g(x)$ is a function of $x^3$ every root $r_i$ should be a triple root.", but this is not what your product indicates. It indicates a function with single roots only. It is a kind of nit-picky thing, but it is still a part that might need minor adjustment.

Comment: Hey @MajidFekri, just wondering if you made any more progress on this? I'm really interested in $/zeta(3)$, so please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: I don't get this bit: "On the other hand, roots of g(x)=0 are given by: 2sin(π/6−√3/2x)=e^(-3x/2) . Are you subtracting infinite series? If so what are they?

Comment: @MDH Use the Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$...

Comment: I'm surprised this gives so accurate a result, as even though r_i & u_i _become_ close to each other, your sum contains terms of low index at which they are _not_ particularly close to the true roots ... and moreover these are the largest terms. So it's curious that the error has somehow conspired to be very small. ¶ I would like to add, though, with all due respect, as this does not change what I have just said: that the approximation is accurate to 5 decimals ... but it _contains 12_ decimals; an approximation is only really _remarkable_ when there is more information out than put in.

Answer (score 9):

*First of all, thank you for the highly interesting question, it provides an excellent exercise!*

---

The error in your approximation is due to taking the roots of $2\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x)=e^{-\frac{3x}{2}}$ when $x\to\infty$ and thus using the asymptotic $2\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x)=0$ instead. In order to alter this error, we examine your function $g(x)$:

$$
g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{3n}}{(3n+2)!}=\frac{e^{-x}\left(2e^{3x/2}\sin(\frac{1}{6}(\pi-3\sqrt3 x))-1\right)}{3x^2},
$$

and note that in order to change the properties of the sine wave on the RHS we need to alter the factorial on the LHS. Let $k$ now denote a positive integer $\geq0$ and examine what happens when we change $(3n+2)!$ to some $(3n+k)!$. In particular, we examine the three cases $k\equiv0 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 3)$, $k\equiv1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 3)$ and $k\equiv2 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 3)$.

---

**Case 1. $k=3j$, $j\in\mathbb{Z}$.**

Let's examine $k=0$ first and generalize later.

$$
g'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{3n}}{(3n)!}=-\frac13 e^{-x} \left(2e^{3x/2}\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)+1\right),
$$

and by similar methods we get $\zeta(3)\cong \frac87\left(\frac{\pi^{3}}{6(3)^{3/2}}\right)=1.136602043\ldots$ which is not a very good approximation. Having $j>0$ yields similar results that include the cosine function, but with some leading $\exp$ terms. For instance, we have for $j=3$:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{3n}}{(3n+9)!}=\frac{e^{-x}\left(-e^{x}x^6+120e^xx^3-720e^x+480e^{3x/2}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2})+240\right)}{720x^9}
,$$

and we can see that when $x\to\infty$ we are making an even bigger error in our approximation by assuming that its roots are those that satisfy the equation

$$
480\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right)=0.
$$

In fact, as $j$ increases so does our error.

---

**Case 2. $k=3j+1$, $j\in\mathbb{Z}$.**

In this case we get similar expressions as your original sine wave, but with some differences in sign (pun not intended). For $j=0$ we have

$$
g'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{3n}}{(3n+1)!}=-\frac{e^{-x}\left(2e^{3x/2}\sin(\frac{1}{6}(\pi+3\sqrt3 x))-1\right)}{3x^2},
$$

which has the same roots as your original function $g(x)$ and the same error in approximating $\zeta(3)$. As in **Case 1**, increasing the value of $j$ leads to even more leading $\exp$ terms and thus increases the error in our approximation.

---

**Case 3. $k=3j+2$, $j\in\mathbb{Z}$.**

The case $j=0$ corresponds to your original function $g(x)$. As with cases **1** and **2**, increasing $j$ increases the amount of leading $\exp$ terms and thus the error in the approximation due to taking the roots of the asymptotic value when $x\to\infty$.

---

It remains to be seen whether it is possible to sensibly generalize the factorial to $(in+j)!$, $i,j\in\mathbb{Z}, i>0$ in order to get other approximations for other odd zeta values, perhaps several of these cases might yield good approximations. Euler himself tried to generalize his proof of the Basel problem to compute values for $\sum_n n^{-(2k+1)}$, $k>0$ but found no way to achieve this. Since then, considerable brain power has been expended to do just that, without success. I believe that is a good indicator that this path might not lead to a nice closed-form expression for $\zeta(3)$ in terms of $\pi^3$.

---

**EDIT 11.12.2018**

Taking the function

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{5n}}{(3n+2)!}=\frac{e^{-x^{5/3}}\left(2e^{3x^{5/3}/2}\sin(\frac{1}{6}(\pi-3\sqrt3 x^{5/3}))-1\right)}{3x^{10/3}}
$$

yields the same approximation as $g(x)$, i.e., with $x^{3n}$ instead of $x^{5n}$ in the sum. This provides further indication that this approach is unlinkely to yield any better results on $\zeta(3)$.